# insert script into div / class

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I am trying to insert a script into a website via tampermonkey.

I tried several approaches but it's not working:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Insert TAG Into Class- zeit.com
// @require  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
// @match       http*://reuters.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = 'https://track.adform.net/adfscript/?bn=XXXXXX';
    $("#contentContainer").append(s);
})();
```

I also tried this:

```
$("#contentContainer").append(`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://track.adform.net/adfscript/?bn=XXXXXX"></script>`)
```

Any idea why neither of these are working?

Comment: Please expand on "it's not working" - are you getting an error in the console? Is anything happening on the page (the wrong element is being changed)? Is nothing happening on the page? How have you tried debugging this so far? Breakpoint debugging with tampermonkey may not be very feasible, but you could always use `console.log()` to inspect values at run-time. Are you sure jQuery is loaded on the page and your selector works?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones: I have added the console log as well bit its not shown in the console either. I tried it also with a class: "Leaderboard__slot___VvllT Leaderboard__floating___1iw6j" but in the console nothing is shown!

Comment: Are you sure tampermonkey is even running on this page? What if you change the entire script to `console.log('Hello world');`? Does that even get printed to your console? What have you done to attempt to debug this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to dynamically insert the ad track script into some page? Maybe you can try this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Insert TAG Into Class- zeit.com
// @require  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
// @match       http*://reuters.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = 'https://track.adform.net/adfscript/?bn=XXXXXX';
    $("body").append(s);
})();
```

Comment: yes I want to insert it into some page!
I used your script as well but it looks like that it is still not working. The console also with console log is also not really shown where the error is.

Comment: What is the error you said worth it?
When I used that script, I found no errors

Comment: Hey @chenc, the tag is written into the page but its not displayed:
The tag has the following ID:

https://track.adform.net/adfscript/?bn=37427896

Cheers,